# Importing lodash in Angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, npm, angular, lodash

I am trying to install lodash in my angular 2 app but there is some error telling me skipping failed optional dependency, and not compatible with your operating system or architecture.

I am running on Windows 10 x64. I already run cmd as admin. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Kindly please help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Those are warnings and can be ignored. If you see inside `node_modules`  folder `lodash` is already installed.

Comment: and how does the import or require line look like? Any other files that need modification?